# How to change all elements of vectors within a list to a value

Tags: r, for-loop

Each element in my list corresponds to a vector. I want to change all the elements in my vectors to a specified value. So for example:

```
x <- c("x1","x2","x3")
y <- list(1:5,1:10,1:15)
Ans <- list()
for (i in 1:length(y)){
  Ans[[i]] <- rep(x[i],length(y[[i]]))  
}
```

This results in:

```
[[1]]
[1] "x1" "x1" "x1" "x1" "x1"

[[2]]
 [1] "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2"

[[3]]
 [1] "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3"
```

Is there a function in R which can handle this?

Comment: `Map(function(a, b) rep(a, length(b)), x, y)`

Comment: Thank you, i'm still transitioning between for-loops and R functionality, excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lengths` with`split`

```
unname(split(rep(x, lengths(y)), rep(seq_along(x), lengths(y))))
#[[1]]
#[1] "x1" "x1" "x1" "x1" "x1"

#[[2]]
# [1] "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2" "x2"

#[[3]]
# [1] "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3" "x3"
```

---

Or with `Map`

```
Map(rep, x, lengths(y))
```